# How can I add new items to the inventory of aspdotnetstorefront

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I want to add stock items in inventory but I couldn't find where is the option to add stock list.Please let me know where can I manage inventory.

Answer (score 1):

For v 9.x, open the Admin User Interface (defaults at http://www.domain.com/admin/)...

For a standard variant:

1. Go to Products Menu > Manage Products
2. Choose a Product
3. Click Show Variants (at top of screen)
4. Click the Variant Name (defaults to "(Unnamed Variant)")
5. Update "Current Inventory" to reflect the quantity you want
6. Save your Variant changes

If you are using Colors and/or Sizes, after you have chosen a product, you need to first:

1. Set "Track Inventory By Size and Color" to "Yes"
2. Then, Click Show Variants (at top of screen)
3. Click the Variant Name (defaults to "(Unnamed Variant)")
4. Click "Manage Inventory"
5. Make your inventory changes
6. Save your updates

Or finally in bulk:

1. Go to Products Menu > Bulk Update Pricing
2. Set your Inventory levels to reflect the quantities you want
3. Click Update All